# Firebase Android Java - Can't get value of a child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have been trying to implement a way to check if the user had already sent a friend a request to the profile visited, or if the user has received a friend request from the profile visited. Based on the results, the buttons will be set to `sent request`, `accept request` ,`add friend` or `friends`

However, in my Firebase function, the first 3 `if` statements aren't met, even if one of them was supposed to be met. The first `else if` statement should have worked because I already sent a friend request to the profile visited.

When I ran a debug, it shows something like `value = {sentFriendRequests={jmarston=2}}`. So Firebase knows that I added John Marston as a friend, but for some reason the `else if` statement wasn't working. Its the `else` statement that works instead

My code is down below:

checkFriendRequestStatus function

```
private void checkFriendRequestStatus(final ButtonStatus buttonsCallback, final String strSignedInUID, final String visitedUsername, final String strVisitedUID) {
        final DatabaseReference checkFriendRequestsRef = database.getReference("friend_requests/test/" + strSignedInUID);
        checkFriendRequestsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                // choice is 1 to show buttons, then select which buttons to show with second params
                if (dataSnapshot.child("friends/" + visitedUsername).getValue(String.class) == strVisitedUID) {
                    buttonsCallback.setButtonStatus(1, 1);
                }
                else if (dataSnapshot.child("sentFriendRequest/" + visitedUsername).getValue(String.class) == strVisitedUID) {
                    buttonsCallback.setButtonStatus(1, 2);
                }
                else if (dataSnapshot.child("receivedFriendRequests/" + visitedUsername).getValue(String.class) == strVisitedUID) {
                    buttonsCallback.setButtonStatus(1, 3);
                }
                else {
                    buttonsCallback.setButtonStatus(1, 4);;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

onViewCreated function

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        sRFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sRUFullNameET);

        addFriendBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sRUAddFriendBtn);
        sentRequestBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sRUFriendReqSentBtn);
        acceptRequestBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sRUAcceptRequestBtn);
        wereFriendsBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sRUWeFriendsBtn);

        final String strVisitedUserID = getArguments().getString("sRUserID");
        final String visitedUsername = getArguments().getString("sRUsername");

        ShPreference = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // converts Stringed userID back to Int
        final String strSignedInUID = ShPreference.getInt(currentUserID, 0) + "";
        final String signedInUsername = ShPreference.getString(currentUsername, "");
        // converts the userSignedIn id to string
        //final String strSignedInUID = userSignedInID + "";

        // checks if the current User visited has been sent a friend Request
        checkFriendRequestStatus(new ButtonStatus() {
            @Override
            public void setButtonStatus(int choice, int button) {
                /**
                 * The choice params is for the choose if to show or hide buttons.
                 * The buttons params selects which buttons are to show or hide
                 */

                addFriendBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sentRequestBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                acceptRequestBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                wereFriendsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // if choosed to show buttons
                if (choice == 1) {
                    // show buttons depending on the friendRequest status
                    if (button == 1) {
                        wereFriendsBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if (button == 2) {
                        sentRequestBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if (button == 3) {
                        acceptRequestBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else {
                        addFriendBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, strSignedInUID, visitedUsername, strVisitedUserID);


        // sets the name with the Full Name; called from SearchResultsAdapter
        sRFullName.setText(getArguments().getString("sRFullName"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To compare String object use equals instead of == (double equals). Double equals will compare reference not their values.**

Update your code of comparison like below:

```
private void checkFriendRequestStatus(final ButtonStatus buttonsCallback, final String strSignedInUID, final String visitedUsername, final String strVisitedUID) {
        final DatabaseReference checkFriendRequestsRef = database.getReference("friend_requests/test/" + strSignedInUID);
        checkFriendRequestsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                // choice is 1 to show buttons, then select which buttons to show with second params
                if (dataSnapshot.child("friends/" + visitedUsername).getValue(String.class).equals(strVisitedUID)) {
                    buttonsCallback.setButtonStatus(1, 1);
                }
                else if (dataSnapshot.child("sentFriendRequest/" + visitedUsername).getValue(String.class).equals(strVisitedUID)) {
                    buttonsCallback.setButtonStatus(1, 2);
                }
                else if (dataSnapshot.child("receivedFriendRequests/" + visitedUsername).getValue(String.class).equals(strVisitedUID)) {
                    buttonsCallback.setButtonStatus(1, 3);
                }
                else {
                    buttonsCallback.setButtonStatus(1, 4);;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```